# ERROR: operator class does not exist for access method "btree"

Tags: postgresql, collation

I've encountered an issue while attempting to execute a script. Here's the scenario:

```
-- Script to create collation
CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive 
(PROVIDER = icu, LOCALE ='und-u-ks-level2', DETERMINISTIC = FALSE);

-- Followed by adding an index using the collation
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX col1_idx ON my_table (col1 case_insensitive);
```

Regrettably, during the indexing process, I encountered the following error:

```
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: operator class "case_insensitive" does not exist for access method "btree"
```

I have checked into `pg_opclass` table and it wasn't exist there:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_opclass WHERE opcname = 'case_insensitive';
```

Any idea what's I'm doing wrong/missing here? I would be immensely grateful for any insights or assistance regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax `(col1 case_insensitive)` is used for [operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html): [`varchar_pattern_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-opclass.html) or [`gin_trgm_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX) as examples of commonly used ones.

[Specific collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-collations.html) in indexes can be used with `COLLATE` keyword:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX col1_idx ON my_table (col1 COLLATE "case_insensitive");
```

---

One can specify both collate and operator class. These are different features.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX col2_idx ON my_table (col1 collate "case_sensitive" text_pattern_ops);
```

Comment: wow.. that helped. Thank you @Melkij